# GMap inside Jquery Mobile page with IScrollView

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, iscroll, iscrollview

I have a webapp created with JQuery Mobile v1.3.2 implementing IScrollView.
When I'm scrolling the map vertically the Scroll View scrolls also.
Is there a way to disable that behaviour, to cancel iscroll scrolling when scrolling the gmap?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the map still seems to propagate touch events to iscroll. Let's try to prevent this by stopPropagation();

**Edit**
Here is the working jQuery mobile [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mwfire/5Arhg/2/)

```
var map_canvas = $('#map_canvas')[0];
// "mousedown" should be "touchstart" on mobile device
$(map_canvas).bind('mousedown', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

A fiddle with plain javascript [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/mwfire/5Arhg/1/)

```
var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
// "mousedown" should be "touchstart" on mobile device
map_canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
}, false);
```

**P.S.**
Find [here](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) The link to the stopPropagation docs, comes in very handy some times ;)